# scrapy returning first item

Tags: python, scrapy

I am learning scrapy for someone reason it is only returning the first item on the page. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Below is the code I have:

```
class RuvillaSpider(Spider):

    name = "RuvillaSpider"
    allowded_domains = ["ruvilla.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.ruvilla.com/men/footwear.html?dir=desc&limit=45&order=news_from_date"]

    def parse(self, response):
        products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="category-products"]')

        if not products:
            raise CloseSpider('RuvillaSpider: DONE, NO MORE PAGES.')

        for product in products:
            item = RuvillaItem()
            item['name'] = product.xpath('ul/li/div/div[1]/a/@title').extract()[0]
            item['link'] = product.xpath('ul/li/div/div[1]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            item['image'] = product.xpath('ul/li/div/div[1]/a/img/@src').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

Comment: Here, apart from defining your class, you are *a priori* doing nothing wrong. What you do with the instance of this class may also be helpfull. This could, for example, show us that you are aware that you are using a generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath seems to return only 1 product for `products` variable.

Try:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.ruvilla.com/men/footwear.html?dir=desc&limit=45&order=news_from_date"
In[1]: response.xpath('//div[@class="category-products"]')
Out[1]: [<Selector xpath='//div[@class="category-products"]' data=u'<div class="category-products">\n<div cla'>]
```

So it seems your xpath is not for every individual item but for the container the items are in. To remedy this you need to generate an xpath that select every *product* container instead:

```
def parse(self, response):
    products = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="category-products"]//li[contains(@class,"item")]')

    for product in products:
        item = dict()
        item['name'] = product.xpath('.//a/@title').extract_first()
        item['link'] = product.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first()
        item['image'] = product.xpath('.//a/img/@src').extract_first()
        yield item
    next_page = response.xpath("//li[@class='current']/following-sibling::li[1]/a/@href").extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield Request(next_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath was wrong.

Use this xpath:

> ('//div[@class="category-products"]/ul/li')